# weighted calculation in list structure data

Tags: list-manipulation, data

```
dataSample = {g[ f[{10009, 10007, 10003, 10005}, {0.22584052329594687`,

0.23987428669761543`, 0.26528870462640836`, 0.26899648538002935`}], {1, 5, 257}],

g[f[{10009, 10007, 10003, 10005, 10002, 10004}, {0.1407652340009867`,

0.14951240638759009`, 0.1653530820756171`, 0.16766412270637168`, 0.17874523988109475`,

0.1979599149483397`}], {1, 3, 85}], g[f[{10009, 10007, 10003, 10005, 10002, 10004},

{0.1407652340009867`, 0.14951240638759003`, 0.1653530820756171`,

0.16766412270637168`, 0.17874523988109475`, 0.1979599149483397`}], {1, 5, 588}], g[f[{10009,

10007, 10003, 10005, 10002, 10004}, {0.1407652340009867`, 0.14951240638759009`,

0.1653530820756171`, 0.16766412270637168`, 0.17874523988109475`,

0.19795991494833973`}], {1, 2, 339}]};

res = Flatten[ Transpose[({#[[1, 1]], Head[#] #[[1, 2]] & /@ (#[[2]] /@

Transpose[(#[[1]] /. f -> List)])} & @ #)] & /@ dataSample, 1]

(*
    {{10009,{0.225841,1.1292,58.041}},{10007,{0.239874,1.19937,61.6477}},{10003,{0.265289,1.32
644,68.1792}},{10005,{0.268996,1.34498,69.1321}},{10009,{0.140765,0.422296,11.965}},{10007
,{0.149512,0.448537,12.7086}},{10003,{0.165353,0.496059,14.055}},{10005,{0.167664,0.502992
,14.2515}},{10002,{0.178745,0.536236,15.1933}},{10004,{0.19796,0.59388,16.8266}},{10009,{0
.140765,0.703826,82.77}},{10007,{0.149512,0.747562,87.9133}},{10003,{0.165353,0.826765,97.
2276}},{10005,{0.167664,0.838321,98.5865}},{10002,{0.178745,0.893726,105.102}},{10004,{0.1
9796,0.9898,116.4}},{10009,{0.140765,0.28153,47.7194}},{10007,{0.149512,0.299025,50.6847}}
,{10003,{0.165353,0.330706,56.0547}},{10005,{0.167664,0.335328,56.8381}},{10002,{0.178745,
0.35749,60.5946}},{10004,{0.19796,0.39592,67.1084}}}
*)
```

the goal is clear, but the progress is not so good, Let's see a element's structure:

```
g[f[{10009, 10007, 10003, 10005}, {0.22584052329594687`, 0.23987428669761543`,

0.26528870462640836`, 0.26899648538002935`}], {1, 5, 257}]
```

Here {10009, 10007, 10003, 10005} is keyList

is {0.22584052329594687`,0.23987428669761543`,0.26528870462640836`,0.26899648538002935`} is valueList

{1,5,257} is some kind of weights.

My solution is a little ugly, any nice methods?

Comment: @Kuba Hi, Your answer is right, I see you've used the option of Thread twice in my two answers, thanks, It's very useful.

Comment: It is very nice, thanks for you second quesiton, I was not aware about `Thread` 3rd arg untill you asked and I did some digging!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Block[{
  f = Transpose[{##}] &,
  g = Function[{x, m}, MapAt[m # &, x, {;; , 2}]]
  },
 Join @@ dataSample
 ]
```

or even "nicer":

```
Block[{
  f = ## &,
  g = {#, Times @@@ Thread[{##2}, List, 1]}\[Transpose] &
  },
 Join @@ dataSample
 ]
```

> ```
> {{10009,{0.225841,1.1292,58.041}},
>  {10007,{0.239874,1.19937,61.6477}},
>  <<37>>,
>  {10008,{0.324194,0.324194,59.3275}},
>  {10001,{0.371523,0.371523,67.9887}}}
> ```